# Snappy DBExpress SQL Executor method

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

Given the following

```
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function TTestClass.NewQuery(const ASql : String) : TSqlQuery;
begin
  Result := TSqlQuery.Create(FConn);
  Result.SQLConnection := FConn;
  Result.Sql.Text := ASql;
  Result.Prepared := True;
end;

{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TTestClass.ExecuteSql(const ASql : String);
begin
  with NewQuery(ASql) do
  try
    ExecSql();
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

How might I create an `ExecSql` method that will populate the parameters of the query?

I tried this overloaded method:

```
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TTestClass.ExecuteSql(const ASql : String; const ParamVals : Array Of Variant);
var
  i : integer;
  Qry : TSqlQuery;
begin
  Qry := NewQuery(ASql);
  with Qry do
  try
    for i := Low(ParamVals) to High(ParamVals) do
      Qry.Params[i].Value := ParamVals[i];
    ExecSql();
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

But I get the error message :

> *Project MyProj.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'No value for parameter 'SomeParam''.*

Putting a watch on Parameter[0] apparently shows the value is set - and the parameter name is as I would expect.  Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong ?

And I have been criticised in the past for using 'Array Of Variant' - I wonder if there is a better way .

Thanks, all.

I found something interesting :

```
ParamByName('SomeParam').Value := 1234567;
```

Gives rise to the same Error Message whereas

```
ParamByName('SomeParam').AsInteger := 1234567;
```

Does not.

It is many years since I have used DBExpress - have I forgotten something ?

**Edit**

I have come up with a method that works, but am not happy with it; By examining the Variant Type of the VALUE I have managed to get some results

```
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TMyTestCase.SetParamValues(const AQuery : TSqlQuery; const ParamVals : Array Of Variant);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to AQuery.Params.Count - 1 do begin
    case VarType(ParamVals[i]) of
      varEmpty  :    AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //The variant is Unassigned.
      varNull  :     AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //The variant is Null.
      varAny  :      AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //Represents a Variant that can hold any value.
      varSmallint  : AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := ParamVals[i];  //16-bit signed integer (type Smallint in Delphi, short in C++).
      varInteger  :  AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := ParamVals[i];  //32-bit signed integer (type Integer in Delphi, int in C++).
      varSingle  :   AQuery.Params[i].AsFloat    := ParamVals[i];  //Single-precision floating-point value (type Single in Delphi, float in C++).
      varDouble  :   AQuery.Params[i].AsFloat    := ParamVals[i];  //Double-precision floating-point value (type double).
      varCurrency  : AQuery.Params[i].AsFloat    := ParamVals[i];  //Currency floating-point value (type Currency).
      varDate  :     AQuery.Params[i].AsDateTime := ParamVals[i];  //Date and time value (type TDateTime).
      varOleStr  :   AQuery.Params[i].AsString   := ParamVals[i];  //Reference to a dynamically allocated UNICODE string.
      varDispatch  : AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //Reference to an Automation object (an IDispatch interface pointer).
      varError  :    AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //Operating system error code.
      varBoolean  :  AQuery.Params[i].AsBoolean  := ParamVals[i];  //16-bit Boolean (type WordBool).
      varVariant  :  AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //Indicates another variant.
      varUnknown  :  AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //Reference to an unknown object (an IInterface or IUnknown interface pointer).
      varShortInt  : AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := ParamVals[i];  //8-bit signed integer (type ShortInt in Delphi or signed char in C++).
      varByte  :     AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := ParamVals[i];  //A Byte.
      varWord  :     AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := ParamVals[i];  //Unsigned 16-bit value (Word).
      varLongWord  : AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := ParamVals[i];  //Unsigned 32-bit value (type LongWord in Delphi or unsigned long in C++).
      varInt64  :    AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := ParamVals[i];  //64-bit signed integer (Int64 in Delphi or __int64 in C++).
      varStrArg  :   AQuery.Params[i].AsString   := ParamVals[i];  //COM-compatible string.
      varString  :   AQuery.Params[i].AsString   := ParamVals[i];  //Reference to a dynamically allocated string (not COM-compatible).
      varArray  :    AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //Indicates a Variant array.
      varByRef  :    AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //Indicates that the variant contains a reference as opposed to a value.
      varTypeMask:   AQuery.Params[i].AsInteger  := VarNull;       //
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Surely I have missed out a step - Why doesnt the query parameter have a type ?

**Edit Again**

My current 'Best' solution is to rely on the programmer supplying the correct types and number of values.  I have posted the full SetParamValues() method above.  This is by NO MEANS thoroughly tested, but hopefully it will assist someone.

Comment: Please show the Value of ASql and the length of ParamVals

Comment: @SirRufo - A use-case might be as follows ExecuteSql('DELETE FROM SOMETABLE WHERE ID = :ID',[1234567]);  Note that the 1st 2 methods work as expected and that parameters are correctly set up according to the content of ASql.

Comment: I do the same, but my param assignment loop is a bit different: for i:= 0 to q.Params.Count - 1 do q.Params[i].Value:= Params[i];.

Comment: @jachguate - I tried that too and the result is the same.  I also tried a ParamByName() approach which was a bit dumb and convoluted, and did not resolve the issue.  What puzzles me is that if I use NewQuery() and then populate the parameters in the calling method, then I have no problem.  I wonder if it is related to the Oracle driver ???  What RDBMS do you use ?

Comment: I use this with different databases, but I'm not sure if there's any call with Oracle. To make a quick test, you can try the DevArt oracle driver.

Comment: @jachguate - see my edit - the problem arises when I use .Value, but goes away if I use .AsInteger (for example)

Comment: Then your parameters can't determine the expected type. Just check the param type. I don't know if dbX provides ParseSQL, or maybe setting prepared := true will solve that

Comment: @Sir Rufo - as you can see from my code snippets I am already setting prepared := True;  Checking Params[i].DataType returns ftUnknown for all parameters.  BLAST !!!!

Comment: yeah, i missed that you already prepare :o)

Comment: Try to set Prepare := True after seting the parameter values.

Comment: @da-soft that doesn't matter. Every statement will be prepared before execution, setting true will force a prepare while setting, setting false will force reprepare on execution http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.Prepared

Comment: yar - I have just switched the order of things and it doesnt really get me anywhere.  It also suggests that Preparing the query is pointless in this case - by definition these are snappy one-liners and not reused.

Comment: Your method will fail if you pass an Integer below 256, because then VarType is `varByte` and `AsByte` will set param datatype to `ftByte` and this leads to the same error. The only workaround is to set param datatype to `ftString` or `ftWideString`.

Comment: Even if I use it like this : "var i :integer; begin i := 254; ExecuteSql(qry,[i]); end;" ???

Comment: @Sir Rufo - Tested fine. Your objection is correct, though, I have to create a variable for each param, which was my intention.  Aha! - just passed a Byte param and got an 'unsupported UINT8' - modified the fragment accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no easy solution for this

---

All tests performed with Delphi XE3 and MySQL

---

**Behavior Explanation**

At designtime you will get the correct parameter data types as long as the parameters depend on a table field from the FROM table without aliases

```
SELECT id FROM items WHERE id = :id
```

but it will also fail if not

```
SELECT id FROM items WHERE id/2 = :id
```

and this will also fail

```
SELECT i.* FROM items i WHERE i.id = :id
```

At runtime both will result in parameters with datatype `ftUnknown`.

Parameters are setup in private method

```
// Delphi XE3
Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.SetParameterFromSQL
```

Inside this method the tablename is extracted and only

```
if csDesigning in ComponentState then
```

a temporary DataSet is created with

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE 0 = 1
```

Every parameter is checked against the fieldnames from this dataset and if names match the parameter datatype is set.

Thats the reason why you get `ftUnknown` for your parameters at runtime.

To solve that Delphi does the same you tried with your solution, but dbexpress fails sometime.
The Setter for parameters is located at

```
Data.DB.TParam.SetAsVariant
```

and value `1234567` has the variant type `varLongword` and parameter datatype will be set to `ftLongword` and causes this error.

---

**Workaround**

As a workaround you can set parameter datatype to ftString/ftWideString, as this will work in **most** cases.

```
procedure TTestClass.ExecuteSql(const ASql : String; const ParamVals : Array Of Variant);
var
  i : integer;
  Qry : TSqlQuery;
begin
  Qry := NewQuery(ASql);
  with Qry do
  try
    for i := Low(ParamVals) to High(ParamVals) do
    begin
      Qry.Params[i].DataType := ftWideString;
      Qry.Params[i].Value := ParamVals[i];
    end;
    ExecSql();
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

To get a better solution you get a procedure to set the parameter datatype to `ftString`/`ftWidestring` only for critical variant types (like your method SetParamValues but more general)

```
procedure SetParamValues( const AParams : TParams; const AValues : array of Variant );
var
  LIdx : Integer;
  LParam : TParam;
  LValue : Variant;
begin
  for LIdx := 0 to Pred( AParams.Count ) do
  begin
    LParam := AParams[LIdx];
    LValue := AValues[LIdx];
    // only handle the critical parts
    case VarType( LValue ) of
      varByte, varLongword : LParam.DataType := ftWideString;
    end;
    // all other will be set here
    LParam.Value := LValue;
  end;
end;
```

---

**Solution: the hard way**

As i first stated there is no easy solution for this. For a full functional solution you have to parse the whole WHERE statement

```
SELECT a.*, b*
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = :id AND b.count / 2 = :halfcount
```

and build a query from this

```
SELECT a.id as Param1, b.count / 2 as Param2
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 0 = 1
```

to get the expected datatype.

---

**Solution: the long way**

IMHO this is a bug and should be reported to EMBA ...

---

**Solution: the expensive way**

I made a test with [UniDAC](http://www.devart.com/unidac/) and everything is the same as dbExpress. Parameter datatype is `ftUnknown` and setting parameter value will set the datatype to `ftLongword`.

But there is one special case: You will not get an error and your query is processed as you expect.

Comment: That is a really superb answer, thanks very much.  Uniquely, because it is part of a unit-testing framework, the majority of sql will be inserts, updates and deletes.  This is because it is all about setting correct conditions for unit-tests to run, and then tidying up afterwards.  I am inclined to agree with you that this is a bug - certainly an undesirable 'feature'.

Comment: @jachguate - Would you be prepared to post some code to demonstrate how you solved this ?  Given Sir Rufo's explanation above I am inclined to stick with my current solution.  My objection to it is somewhat theoretical (not production code etc), but you may have achieved a better result in any case.

Comment: The String workaround is something I have used in the past quite successfully.  The big 'gotcha' is TDateTime, of course.  To solve that I found the best solution was to set the DateTime format on the Db server to match the client.  This approach makes international issues go away.  I am lucky to be using Oracle, but presumably most of the Db systems have this facility.

Comment: looks like the bounty is yours.  Thanks for your help.